# how to pass city name in parmalink structure of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a static front page in Wordpress and I want to use a city name in the permalink so that I can change the contents of the page on the basis of the detected city. However, when I try to add a rule, it takes me to the wrong page. Here is a sample of the code I'm trying to use:

```
$wp_rewrite->add_rule('^city-([^/]*)/?$','index.php?cityNameParma=$matches[1]','top');
```

It's for a page which will display businesses directory listings. Upon clicking I added a new rule
which should allow inner pages to work as intended:

```
$wp_rewrite->add_rule('^city-([^/]*)/wpbdm-category/([^/]*)/?$','index.php?wpbdm-category=$matches[2]&cityNameParma=$matches[1]','top');
```

I then get the city name from the URL with

```
$wp_query->query_vars['cityNameParma'];
```

The only problem that remains is how to get the value when a static home page is called and how I send the parameter value as I have done for inner pages.

Kindly help me out as I have melted my brain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you also have to add your new parameter to the accepted query-params:

```
function my_query_vars( $qvars )
{
    $qvars[] = 'cityNameParma';
    return $qvars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query_vars');
```

then you can access it in your template files like you described:

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->query_vars['cityNameParma'];
```

Comment: yes i have alredy have the method inplace and it is working properly as intended but my problem is that when i add it for home page it display me  404 page not found